# How can i order queryresults by the PK of a m2m-relationtable?

Tags: django

I have a model with a m2m relation to users:

```
class SomeModel(models.Model):
    user=models.ManyToManyField(User,related_name='linked',blank=True,null=True)
```

to which i have a query:

```
linked_objects=SomeModel.objects.filter(user__id__contains=request.user.id)
```

The results are the ordered by the user id. What i want to do, is to sort the results by the primary key of the relation table between User and SomeModel, which would be appname_somemodel_user. Is this possible?

Comment: That `user__id__contains` doesn't seem to make sense.

Comment: Why not? It just checks if the request.user is one of the users of SomeModel.

Comment: No, it does not do that. That would be `SomeModel.objects.filter(user__id=request.user.id)`. But a more simple and equivalent syntax is `SomeModel.objects.filter(user=request.user)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Might be wrong about this, but I think you can only refer to the intermediary table if you specify it yourself explicitly.

```
class SomeModel(models.Model):
    user=models.ManyToManyField(User,related_name='linked',blank=True,null=True, through='SomeModelUser')

class SomeModelUser(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User)
    some_model = models.ForeignKey(SomeModel)

linked_objects=SomeModel.objects.filter(user__id__contains=request.user.id).order_by('somemodeluser__pk')
```

Comment: Doesn't work properly. I alway get the message 'SomeModel' object has no attribute 'somemodeluser'.

Comment: What version of Django are you using? Works fine for me both with 1.1 and 1.2. Although I concur with @TomaszZielinski that `user__id__contains` does not make sense, however it does work.

Comment: I use 1.2. Why doesn't ´user__id__contains´ make sense? I ask because i don't understand why it doesn't make sense, which shows me i misunderstood something.

Comment: @marue: If you check [http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.2/ref/models/querysets/#contains](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.2/ref/models/querysets/#contains) and/or test it with a specific user ID, it's pretty evident. If user with ID=1 accesses the page, it will return all `SomeModel` that belong to any user that has an ID which contains `1`... so 11, 12, 13..., 21 and so on.

Comment: ah - ok. that makes sense - strange i din't realize that.